# Why is my newly installed phpmyadmin on Ubuntu LAMP server showing a distorted UI?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Does anyone know why my phpmyadmin won't load correctly? I just installed LAMP and phpmyadmin through ubuntu into my server. But when I load into into phpmyadmin, it showing this hardly readable phpmyadmin ui.
[After Login UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iyCE.png)

[Before Login UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTXvV.png)

Try to open it using other devices, refreshed it many times... but still showing this basic(?) layout rather than the usual layout.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the problem seems to be mostly styling based on the limited information you've given, I'd assume your problem is in mapping of your files or simply put, something went wrong in installation.

I would suggest just reinstalling phpmyadmin to see if it will correct itself.

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

This also explains getting it back after the purge [Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-22-04)

If it's not that, the only other thing I could think of would be file/directory permissions preventing access to the theme/css files needed. And, unless you did the installation manually copying files yourself that's very unlikely.